# How to get the session id in FTL

Tags: freemarker

I want the current session id in the ftl page.

I tried many things with the Session (HttpSessionHashModel) available but not able to get the id?

Getting a request header also do my job.

Is there any way to get any of these item in my FTL?

Answer (score 0):

you can put the parameter in your FTL file with java servlet.

I think your project work like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {

        try
        {
            Map dataModel = new HashMap();

            dataModel.put("session_id", req.getSession().getId());                

            Configuration cfg = new Configuration();

            Template tmpl = cfg.getTemplate("test.ftl");

            tmpl.process(dataModel, resp.getWriter());
        }
        catch (TemplateException ex) {               
            throw new IOException(ex);
        }

    }
```

file test.ftl as

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <p> ${session_id!""} </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand that this is just an example, but can you still indicate hat `Configuration` should be a singleton and hence not being reinstantiated for each request. Because, people like to copy-parse...

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker doesn't expose anything by default. It doesn't even know what servlets are. So it depends on the web application framework your are using. (Unless, you are using `freemarker.ext.servlet.FreeMarkerServlet`.) Or, you can put these into the data-model directly.

Comment: But i am user freemarker servlet and HttpRequestHashModel is available as Request. Can I get session or request headers from this.

Comment: No, `FreemarkerServlet` only exposes the session attributes. You could extend `FreemarkerServlet` and override `createModel` to add the session ID via `AllHttpScopesHashModel.putUnlistedModel` to the return value of `super.createModel`.